# Using Cocoa Auto-Layout inside a view based NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview, autolayout

My goal is to create a table view that shows short, but variable length and multi-line, messages with a picture (like a list of tweets for example). I have decided to try using Auto-Layout for the views that will be added to the table because I'm hoping it will simplify development in the long run, but I'm having issues with layout constraints.

I want each table row view to expand in height to accommodate the text content, but have a fixed width that is the full width of the table view. This fixed width will change only when the window is resized.

I'm still learning how best to use Auto-Layout, but having difficulty getting my head around how it would work in this context.

Does the table view need to be explicitly given the height of each row? If so, where is this done, and if not how can I force the view to size correctly to fit the content?

I was using `(CGFloat)tableView:heightOfRow:` before in a horrible solution without auto-layout that didn't work well. If I don't need to give the height, how will the table view get the height to give the row? It seems like the tableview embeds my custom view into another view, and that one does not expand to fit, but I'm not certain of this.

My view hierarchy is approximately the following:

```
 - Window
   - Custom titlebar
   - Scroll View
     - Table View
       - Row View (variable height)
         - Text View
       - Row View (variable height)
         - Text View
       - Row View (variable height)
         - Text View
```

I hope I have described the problem well enough, if not let me know in the comments and I'll add some more detail or diagrams.

Comment: If you have variable height rows, then tableView:heightOfRow: is the method you're supposed to use.